# font-size scaled in IE8?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

[In IE8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6CLN.png)

[In IE7 and other browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2qC4.png)

both page scaled in 100%.I found font-size in IE8 and only in IE8 was bigger than other browser.Is anyone can tell me the reasion and solution ?

here is the html and css:

```
        <div class="a_ticket-box">
                    <a href="" class="a_ticket" id="a_ticket_en">
                        <img id="a_ticket_btag_en" src="../img/tag-en.png" alt="">
                        <h4 id="en-buy">PURCHASE TICKET</h4>
                        <p id="en-p">Newly added March 5-6 fifth floor ticket</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
```

THX

Comment: Post your CSS as well

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your css code. As I see in html you don't have specified font size inside paragraph. Browsers can interpretate default font size in < p> different. You should set font size in css like:

```
#en-p {
 font-size: 1em;
}
```

Or inline inside paragraph like:

```
<p id="en-p" style="font-size: 1em;">Newly added March 5-6 fifth floor ticket</p>
```

Comment: How can you see there is no font size set when you can't see the CSS?